# Автоматизация написания кода. С чего начать?

Tags: python-3.x, архитектура

Мне нужно писать скрипты для автоматических тестов и я хочу ускорить этот процесс и заодно максимально его автоматизировать.
Тесты нам присылают в виде текстов, чаще всего в ПДФ. В тексте есть ключевые слова, по которым можно определить **что нужно сделать**, **какой элемент проверить** или какой **параметр установить в то или иное значение**. Так же в тестах попадаются множество однотипных задач, которые я пока выполняю копи-пастом.

Хочу я это написать на питоне. Сейчас имею короткий скрипт, который ищет в тексте ключевые слова, в три захода и всталяет нужный кусок кода:

**какой элемент проверить** -> **какое должно быть состояние** -> **вставить кусок кода**.

Ключевые слова храню в массиве, куски кода в словаре.
На данный момент имею ограниченную базу слов и кода. Попал в логический тупик: что делать дальше, за что браться первым?

UPD

Я хочу реализовать добавление новых пар (слово-код), нужно расширить список ключевых слов. Пока есть только названия клапанов, ламп и состояния: "открыто", "закрыто", "горит", "не горит". Я же хочу более сложную проверку. Например, что бы прога читая строку "ПРОВЕРЬ НЕ ГОРИТ ЛИ ЛАМПА ПОЖАР ПРИ ОТСУТСТВИИ СИГНАЛА С ДАТЧИКА ДЫМА?" - писала код "ПРОВЕРИТЬ ДАТЧИК ДЫМА И ЛАМПУ ПОЖАР"

Comment: @jfs спасибо, я подумаю

Comment: Хотите написать свой [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)?  Если получится, не говорите тем, кто присылает вам тесты ;)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev дело в том, что по политике безопасности я могу использовать только ограничений перечень софта, да и тематика и специфика тестирования специфична. Мне же нужно рещить задачу перевода текста в код, хотя бы отчасти.

Comment: @Ximerik, как я понял, у вас получилось какое-то свое решение, но чем-то не устраивает? Поясните в вопросе, а то сейчас не понятно, что за логический тупик (может быть и не нужно ничего улучшать, если и так есть рабочее решение?)

Comment: @insolor, я хочу реализовать добавление новых пар (слово-код), нужно расширить список ключевых слов. Пока есть только названия клапанов, лам и состояния: "открыто", "закрыто", "горит", "не горит". Я же хочу более сложную проверку. Например, что бы прога читая строку "ПРОВЕРЬ НЕ ГОРИТ ЛИ ЛАМПА ПОЖАР ПРИ ОТСУТСТВИИ СИГНАЛА С ДАТЧИКА ДЫМА?"

Comment: ... писала код "ПРОВЕРИТЬ ДАТЧИК ДЫМА И ЛАМПУ ПОЖАР "

Comment: @Ximerik, добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Cucumber, Concordion, Behat. Судя по тому что вы пишете, вам нужен один из этих фреймворков. Под python был PyConcordion.

Comment: @nick_gabpe Спасибо!